# C# how to call a void method from another class in a while loop

Tags: c#, winforms, filesystems

So I have 2 classes: `ImageScanner` and `Form1`

What I want to do is keep calling the **`ScreenCapture`** method in my while loop until a certain condition is met.

This Method captures my screen and saves the screenshot as a `PNG` file in the same place. This means every time I take a screenshot, the new one replaces the old one.

I am trying to do this when I click a button on my form so I don't know why C# is giving me an error.

I can however call the **`ScreenCapture`** method when it is not in my loop.

```
class ImageScanner
    {
        public static void ScreenCapture()
        {
            var bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,
                                           Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height,
                                           PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);

            // Create a graphics object from the bitmap.
            var gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);

            // Take the screenshot from the upper left corner to the right bottom corner.
            gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
                                        Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
                                        0,
                                        0,
                                        Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size,
                                        CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

            // Save the screenshot to the specified path that the user has chosen.
            bmpScreenshot.Save("Screenshot.png", ImageFormat.Png);
        }
    }



public partial class ClickForm : Form
{
    private void ECFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int j = 0;

        while (j < 20)
        {
            j += 1;
            ImageScanner.ScreenCapture();
        }
        MessageBox.Show("found");
    }
}
```

**Error Message:**

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+.
> at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)
> at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageFormat format)
> at AutoClicker.ImageScanner.ScreenCapture() in C:\Users\User1\source\repos\AutoClicker\AutoClicker\ImageScanner.cs:line 32
> at AutoClicker.ClickForm.ECFile_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\User1\source\repos\AutoClicker\AutoClicker\Form1.cs:line 232
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
> at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

Comment: " I don't know why C# is giving me an error." - What error? Please provide more details

Comment: "unhandled exception has occurred in your application"

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Added the exception

Comment: Did you try to debug th check which line in the code throws the exception?

Comment: Yes, it's only happening when I call the method in the while loop. When I take it out and call it once, it runs fine.

Comment: It might be tied to trying to save the image under the same filename too quickly. Try using a different name for the images in the loop, or adding some delay. Or event better: Opoen a stream, keep it open, and just rewrite to it on every iterations

Comment: this is where you need threading. this kind of error too common for winform. you can find reference everywhere

Comment: That's what I thought too, so I added 7 sec delay after the screencapture method and the error still happen instantly. This means my delay method didn't even get to run.

Comment: can you add using to new bitmap and enclose everything in the bracket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is generally happening due to permission limitation, give enough permission to the folder you save to

As you can see it is stuck in

> System.Drawing.Image.Save

the good practice to start with giving Everyone full control, then after test and pass try to **reduce** the permission.

When saving a file, you should provide a full path including the Directory, folder, file, and file extension. Example: `C:\abcd\filename.bmp`

**Out of subject but good to mention:** Also, consider you are dealing with external resources so there will be a delay of input and output, it is recommended to put after saving command `Thread.Delay(someseconds)` as well, especially, if you save and use the saved file by another code directly (like dealing with temp files).

Comment: I checked the folder permission and it has everything for SYSTEM permission: "Full control", "read", "write", "execute", etc

Comment: @jun try disabling (comment out ) the line of Save `bmpScreenshot.Save("Screenshot.png", ImageFormat.Png);` and tell us the result, what will happen?

Comment: It works when I comment out that line. I mean the code runs, but of course my screen shot doesnt get saved.

Comment: @jun OK great, at least we became closer to the reason

Comment: @jun now, create a folder c:\abcd and provide the Everyone Full permission and attach the permission screenshot so I be sure we speak same language

Comment: @jun by the way Delay is important lets say 10 seconds

Comment: IT WORKED! thanks! Please edit your answer to that so people can see it. Even without delay it works by the way. I just had to save it to a folder instead of where the code was.

Comment: @jun Great, no worries, apply for the same permission on the folder you save and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try Converting the image to stream before saving. Refer link below.

```
Image image;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        }

        image.Save(...);
```